# Creating a circle connected with vertical line and display text on right side of each circle

Tags: html, css

I am creating a circle connected with a line and display the text on right side.
I tried below code If I remove the `display: block` form class `.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle` then the text is displaying on the right side but the circle does not display properly.

Would you help me out in this?

I need output like this

[image]

```css
.info-timeline ul{list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.info-timeline ul li{margin: 10px;}
.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle{
   position: relative;
 border: 2px solid #999;
 border-radius: 100%; 
 width: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 50px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 2;
 display: block;
}
.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle:before {
 position: absolute; 
 border: 1px solid #999;
 width: 0; 
 height: 50px; 
 display: block;
 content: ''; 
 left: 50%; 
 z-index: 1; 
 top: -54px; 
 margin-left: -1px;
 }
.info-timeline ul li:first-child {margin-top: 0;}
.info-timeline ul li:first-child:before {display: none;}

.info-timeline ul li a{color: #000;}
```

```html
 <div class="info-timeline">
  <ul>
   <li><span class="timeline-circle">1</span><a href="#">example 1</a></li>
   <li><span class="timeline-circle">2</span><a href="#">example 2</a></li>
   <li><span class="timeline-circle">3</span><a href="#">example 3</a></li>
   <li><span class="timeline-circle">4</span><a href="#">example 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you have an answer now for what you were doing. However, have you also considered using an HTML5 canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` instead, you also need to remove the margin for it to connect:

```css
.info-timeline ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info-timeline ul li:not(:first-of-type) span.timeline-circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -54px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.info-timeline ul li a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-timeline">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="timeline-circle">1</span><a href="#">example 1</a></li>
    <li><span class="timeline-circle">2</span><a href="#">example 2</a></li>
    <li><span class="timeline-circle">3</span><a href="#">example 3</a></li>
    <li><span class="timeline-circle">4</span><a href="#">example 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me to remove the top border?

Comment: That comes from `body`, have a look now :)

Comment: But in the snippet it showing it. I need to remove the top border of the circle 1.

Comment: I can't see this border you're on about, what browser are you using?

Comment: I also can see a border above circle 1 in the latest Chrome. It also is showing in Firefox and Edge.

Comment: I checked in the chrome and Mozilla both. It showing the border.

Comment: I am guessing you can change this line `.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle:before` to this `.info-timeline ul li span.timeline-circle:not(:first-child):before`

Comment: @kojow7,  All the lines go off if I update the class.

Comment: Ah I understand now, have a look now

Comment: Yes, jaunt is correct. It is the `<li>` elements that are siblings, not the timeline-circle ones. :)

Comment: @jaunt, Now it's working perfectly, Thanks for the help. Upvote form my side

Comment: @kojow7 and jaunt, Can you help out in this below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905248/how-to-display-data-fetch-record-twice-in-the-single-page